# NVIDIA drivers causing blank screen with X mouse icon

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I recently decided to switch to the NVIDIA proprietary drivers on my Linux Mint 16 desktop. I added the `xorg-edgers` PPA and installed the `nvidia-current` package.  Upon rebooting, I didn't get the usual Linux Mint logo and instead I got a blank screen with the X mouse cursor.

I tried to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open a new terminal, but that did not do anything.

It seems like X is starting correctly, but the drivers are not loading.  I'd like to just uninstall the drivers, but I can't even get a terminal.  Is there a way to salvage my system without doing a re-install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was actually kind of obscure but easy.  I have two graphics cards in my computer, a PCI-express graphics card which I use, and an onboard discrete graphics controller on my motherboard, which I don't use.

Just out of curiosity, I tried plugging in my monitor to the onboard graphics DVI out and suddenly I got a desktop, albeit not a nice looking one.  I'm guessing the drivers attempted to use the first graphics card it found on my computer (the onboard discrete graphics controller) instead of the one I actually wanted to use.

I went into my BIOS settings and disabled the onboard graphics.  Things booted up correctly after that.

I hope this helps anyone in the future having problems with the NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ssh-server installed on your pc, you can remotely log in and uninstall the drivers from another computer/phone/tablet. Or you could start in safe mode from grub menu, this might help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206465

Basically, hold shift while booting to get into your recovery mode